# How do different initial guesses for the power method converge differently.

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For $$B=\begin{pmatrix}7&-3\\ -3&7\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{40}$$

if we start with $x_₀=\begin{pmatrix}0.95\\ 0.92\end{pmatrix}$ as our initial guess, the power method starts to converge after 16 iterations, meanwhile if we start with $x_₀=\begin{pmatrix}0.95\\ -0.92\end{pmatrix}$ convergence starts in about 12 less iterations, why is that? and why does the power method never seem to converge to the most dominant eigenvalue when we take $x_₀$ that is orthogonal on its eigen vector?

I have read multiple relevant answers about this and couldn't find specific answers to my question.

Comment: What is your algorithm given initial guess?

Comment: Power iteration, the normal way where we repeatedly multiply by $x_i$ and divide by the most dominant no. in $x$ each time

Comment: Then your iteration count is suspicious. It should be double the number. You get your iteration numbers only for the Euclidean norm or if you calculate or print only in single precision.

Answer (score 2):

Your first vector is close to the eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ to the eigenvalue $10$ (ignoring that strange factor $\frac1{40}$ that will not change the qualitative picture) while the second is close to the eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\-1}$ to the eigenvalue $4$. The coefficients in the eigenbasis are $0.935$ and $0.015$ with signs and order changed for the second case.

The formula for the numerical eigenvalue in the $(k+1)$th step is
$$
\lambda_{k+1}=\frac{\|10^{k+1}c_1v_1+4^{k+1}c_2v_2\|_2}{\|10^{k}c_1v_1+4^{k}c_2v_2\|_2}
=
10\sqrt{\frac{c_1^2+c_2^22.5^{-2k-2}}{c_1^2+c_2^22.5^{-2k}}}
=
10\sqrt{1-\frac{c_2^22.5^{-2k}(1-2.5^{-2})}{c_1^2+c_2^22.5^{-2k}}}
$$
The norm computation has this simple form as the eigenvectors are orthogonal and of equal length. To get the eigenvalue approximation to maximal accuracy one thus needs approximately $\left|\frac{c_2}{c_1}\right|<2.5^k\sqrt{2\mu}=2.5^k2^{-26}$, assuming computation in double precision 64bit floating point numbers.

The quotient of the coefficients is $0.0160427807486631$ in the first case, giving $k\approx 15.158$ for the end of the iteration. In the second case the ratio is $-62.33333333333333$, giving $k\approx24.178$.

Note that at this point in the iteration, only about half of the digits of the coordinates of the eigenvectors have stabilized.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it in some generality. Let $A$ be a (diagonalizable) $2\times2$ matrix, let it have eigenvalues $r,s$ with respective eigenvectors $u,v$ and with $|r|<|s|$. Then $u,v$ form a basis for ${\bf R}^2$, so any $x$ in ${\bf R}^2$ can be written as $x=au+bv$ for some real numbers $a,b$. Then for $n=0,1,2,\dots$, $A^nx=ar^nu+bs^nv$. Divide by $s^n$ to get $s^{-n}A^nx=a(r/s)^nu+bv$. So as $n\to\infty$ there is convergence to $bv$.

Now the convergence is faster if $|a|$ is small and $|b|$ is relatively large. See how this applies to your example.

Comment: But how is this even related to the initial guess?

Comment: I think what you're calling "the initial guess" is what I'm calling $x$. Your "power method" involves multiplying your initial guess repeatedly by your matrix (and dividing by some number), right? So, that's my $A^nx$.

Comment: Yes, I get that but I can't relate it to "different initial guesses leading to different convergence speeds"

Comment: Different initial guess means different $x$ means different $a,b$. $a$ much less than $b$ means faster convergence, $b$ much less than $a$ means slower convergence.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, its trivial that if I take $x$ as my eigenvector it converges instantaneously, now how about if I take some arbitrary $x$ it should be someway related, perhaps by the inner product with the $v$, because that's what I noticed after solving a set of problems on the topic.

Comment: Since your matrix is symmetric, its eigenvectors are orthogonal, so inner products do the job. In the general case, eigenvectors are not orthogonal, so inner products are less useful, but still it's just a question of the relative sizes of the eigenvalues and the relative sizes of the coefficients of the eigenvectors.